# Single Responsibility principle : How to determine the number of responsibilities a class is having?

Tags: solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I am going through SRP principle. It states that a class should only have a single reason of change, which implicitly implies that it should have a single responsibility.

I am a bit confused as how would a developer determine if a class has only a single responsibilty?

Is it like if a class is having a single PUBLIC method(with multiple private methods) then it is termed to have a single responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

SRP is a principle not a rule.

A responsibility, or reason to change, refers to a person having reason to change the code at design time. It doesn't refer to the object having a reason to change at runtime.

So for example a view class would have reason to change if someone wanted a button on the UI moved. A database access class would have reason to change if someone wanted to change the database schema.

Imagine the horror if the view and database access were done in the same class.

The principle is to isolate parts of the code so that changes can be made in different areas independently (eg view and database access). That's useful if multiple developers are working on the codebase simultaneously. It's also useful for a single developer not to break other areas when making changes to another.

It's a principle not a rule. In practice classes and modules will often have multiple reasons to change if you squint at them close enough. The principle is really to reduce this, to take out the low hanging fruit rather than to religiously cleanse the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

A Responsibility is about users using the system, ask yourself 'If a user wanted this changed' what else does it need to effect, then what else would it affect.

For example, If I had a 'Student' object with a 'Add course method' and a 'Save' method,

Adding a new course to the student should not need to affect how the student data is saved, but if I changed the 'Add course' method I would need to recompile and redeploy everything relating to saving the student, let's postulate that is implemented as a database.

It's worse still If I wanted to deploy the database separately to the student data structure, or save the student on a different kind of database, or perhaps config files . Those two things are now coupled, and have become rigid.

The users who care about the database are affected by the users who care about the student.

So the best thing to do if you want to determine if the class has one responsibility is to ask what would be affected if you called it's method.

Many classes that have only one responsibility will also have only one method, but others won't, it's definitely not a requirement.

sources:

[Object Mentor](http://objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf)

[Clean Coder videos Ep. 9](http://cleancoders.com/)